# PropertyChangedCallback - first call?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

**OnIconScaleChange** called every time when I change the property **IconScale**
but never called on startup. (with default value = 50.0 )
Tell me how to modify the code to **OnIconScaleChange** invoked the first time on create a UserControl?

```
private static void OnIconScaleChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl c = (MyControl)d;

    if (c != null)
    {
        double v = (double)e.NewValue;
        ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform(v, v);
        c.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
    }
}

public double IconScale
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(IconScaleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IconScaleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IconScaleProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("IconScale", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(50.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIconScaleChange)));
```

Comment: Bind to value other than default value (50.0)

Comment: I thought about it. But it's not a nice solution.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` as name suggest will only be called once the property changes so why do you expect it to be called at first place then?

Comment: Set the default value, it is also uncertain state of change.
As I thought. But apparently it is not. ;)

Comment: How are you setting the default value?

Comment: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(50.0 ...

Comment: @Mixer - Definitely not. Two ways only - Either change default value to something else or set it to value other than default value.

Comment: Why do you test for `c != null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `RenderTransform` in the constructor of MyControl:

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(IconScale, IconScale);
}
```